# How to escape single quotes in csv files？

Tags: csv, neo4j

Recently, I used the ’neo4j-admin import‘ command to import a csv file. In the file, some data is at the beginning of the single quote --> ’.
However, this will result in an error and the file can not be imported.

```
500521802000056;'Mr.Tian Market;13016433146;20160917
```

I have tried to use such an escape character: \'.

```
500521802000056;\'Mr.Tian Market;13016433146;20160917
```

Although importing in this way will not give an error, but in the neo4j display, did not escape the single quotes, but in the form of a string exists in neo4j, when I use swagger to call the interface query, the returned json array It’s like this：

```
"data": {
    "id": 0,
    "mnoId": "500521802000056",
    "name": "\'Mr.Tian Market",
    "tel": "13016433146",
    "day": "20160917",
    "mnos": null
  },
```

Comment: try double quotes around the whole field

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 for replying, but I tried adding double quotes around the whole field, when I use swagger to call the interface query, the returned json array It’s like this：`""'Mr.Tian Market""`

Comment: open your csv file in notepad, and replace all single inverted comma to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem. In the neo4j-admin import command, there is a --quote parameter, you can set whether the quotes you need are double quotes or single quotes.